# What happened to reverse flash after undoing flashpoint?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the original timeline, after reverse flash did his killing business he was stuck in the past. He develops his 20 year master plan to return to his future, impersonating some one and manipulating events 20 years long in his favor.

After restoring the timeline (undoing flashpoint) together with Barry, if I remember right, it looks as if Barry was exhausted and reverse flash returned him back to his present in front of his house and after that, leaves. If this is true, then he didn't get stuck 20 years ago in the past and the timeline should have changed again dramatically. The main villian of season 1 would not be there. And we know from dialogs later in season 3 that he still was.

So what happened to reverse flash after he brought Barry back to his present? How managed he to get stuck 20 years in the past reserving the timeline? Or did he voluntary go back 20 years again, exhausting his energy to preserve the timeline instead of just returning home (or try to start from the present instead of 20 years ago)?

Comment: Nobody any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Reverse Flash was a time remnant. The Arrow Wiki says this

> However, the version of Eobard that helped Barry undo Flashpoint was fully aware that he himself was a time remnant due to his ancestor Eddie Thawne's suicide. As a result, he had to constantly keep moving in order to stay ahead of Hunter Zolomon, who had been turned into an enforcer of the Speed Force, and was trying to correct the aberration that Thawne had become due to the fact that he wasn't supposed to exist in the current timeline. - http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Time_remnant

Then under Hunter Zoloman it says

> The Speed Force deployed the Black Flash to hunt down the Reverse-Flash ever since he and Barry Allen returned to 2016 following the erasing of Flashpoint, to a world where Eobard Thawne wasn't supposed to exist and therefore was a paradoxical threat. As soon as Eobard parted ways with Barry he was beset and immediately outmatched by the demonic speedster who proceeded to track and pursue him relentlessly across time. - http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter_Zolomon

Ultimately:

> Looking on in horror as the black-clad spectral speedster appeared on the horizon, the Reverse-Flash attempted to flee but the Black Flash caught up to him in an eye-blink, seized him by the throat and viciously phased his hand through Eobard's chest, obliterating his heart and causing him, and by extension his time remnants, to be erased from existence.