# How does the Reverse Flash / Eobard Thawne still exist?

Tags: the-flash-2014, the-flash

In the finale episode, "Fast Enough", or Season 1 Episode 23 Eddie shoots himself in the heart in order to stop the Reverse Flash. But, later in season 2, we see the Reverse Flash gets trapped in the past again. How can he be back if  Eddie is gone?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242140/how-is-eobard-thawne-still-alive and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183892/what-happened-to-reverse-flash-after-undoing-flashpoint

Answer (score 1):

This Reverse Flash is a [time remnant](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Time_remnant). I don't believe it's explicitly stated how this time remnant was created, but it's possible that Barry caused it when he pulled him out of the timeline and created [Flashpoint](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Flashpoint_(event)). Harry says:

> It's possible Eobard was in the Speed Force, protecting him like a
> bomb shelter, keeping him alive and his timeline intact. It's what's
> known as a timeline remnant.

and

> ...there is nothing I can do about it. There's nothing you can do about
> it. This is his origin story, and it's going to happen no matter what
> you do.

Comment: Yes. I remember both of these phrases quite well. I just hadn't understood how it all worked. So if he keeps himself in the speed-force, no matter what they did to erase him, we is still in existence?

Comment: @Mintvbz Once the show introduces the concept of time remnants, it becomes very important to the plot. It may make more sense, once you've finished watching season 2.

Comment: Yes. I did a little more research and figured it out. Thanks.